# Fetch Tables with Only One Record and One Table with Several Records

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a prepared statement that INNER JOINS 7 tables and sends an email of all the information gathered. Each table can only have one record per person except the uploaded_files table can have many records for one person.

Everything works great except when there are multiple records in the uploaded_files table then I just receive an empty array error and the email doesn't send. So I am assuming I need to loop through my loop to find multiple records in the uploaded_field table but I can't seem to figure it out.

So there can be only one of every variable except $file_id, $file_name, $file_type, $file_size, and $file_path

I have somewhat simplified the code below so every variable in every table doesn't overshadow the actual issue. thanks for any help you can provide.

```
if(!mysqli_connect_errno())    {
    if($stmt = $db_connect->prepare("SELECT 
    s.student_id, s.student_first_name, s.student_last_name, 
    y.agency_id, y.user_email, y.agency_name, y.agency_rep_name, y.agency_phone, 
    p.personal_id, p.english_name, p.gender, p.date_of_birth, p.fathers_name, p.fathers_email, p.fathers_date_of_birth, p.fathers_phone_number, p.fathers_occupation, p.mothers_name, p.mothers_email, p.mothers_date_of_birth, p.mothers_phone_number, p.mothers_occupation, p.address_1, p.address_2, p.city, p.province, p.country, p.postal_code, p.home_phone, p.mobile_phone, p.in_grade, p.starting_grade, p.medical_insurance, p.homestay_placement, 
    e.emergency_id, e.emerg_first_name, e.emerg_last_name, e.emerg_email, e.emerg_relationship, e.emerg_home_phone, e.emerg_mobile_phone, e.emerg_address_1, e.emerg_address_2, e.emerg_postal_code, e.emerg_city, e.emerg_province, e.emerg_country, 
    a.academic_id, a.school_choice_1, a.school_choice_2, a.school_choice_3, a.preferred_community, a.study_duration, a.needs_canadian_credits, a.arrival_date, a.final_school_date, a.departure_date, a.years_of_english, a.speaking_english, a.writing_english, a.subject_area_1, a.subject_area_2, a.subject_area_3, a.subject_area_4, a.subject_area_5, a.subject_area_6, a.required_courses, a.graduation_goals, a.education_goals, a.semester_start, a.legalization, 
    m.aboutme_id, m.nationality, m.religion, m.language_at_home, m.siblings, m.how_many_siblings, m.lived_in_english_country, m.which_english_country, m.how_long_in_english_country, m.personality, m.family_preference, m.dietary_requirements, m.my_dietary_requirements, m.food_preference, m.fav_foods, m.least_fav_foods, m.reading_genre, m.social_media, m.additional_info, m.hobbies, m.play_instrument, m.which_instrument, m.like_sports, m.which_sports, m.belong_to_clubs, m.which_clubs, m.religious_service, m.prefer_religious_service, m.household_chores, m.have_curfew, m.weekday_curfew, m.weekend_curfew, m.expectations, m.been_away_from_family, m.concerns_about_canada, m.allergies_medical_disabilities, m.airport_pickup, 
    f.file_id, f.file_name, f.file_type, f.file_size, f.file_path 
    FROM students AS s 
        INNER JOIN agency AS y 
        INNER JOIN personal_information AS p USING(student_id) 
        INNER JOIN emergency_information AS e USING(student_id) 
        INNER JOIN academic_information AS a USING(student_id) 
        INNER JOIN aboutme_information AS m USING(student_id) 
        INNER JOIN uploaded_files AS f USING(student_id) 
    WHERE p.student_id AND 
          e.student_id AND 
          a.student_id AND 
          m.student_id AND 
          f.student_id = ? AND 
          y.agency_id = ?") 
    or die('Something Went Wrong')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $student_id, $agency_id);
        /* Execute it */
        $stmt->execute();
        /*Store Results*/
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* Get Number of Rows */
        $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows; 
        $stmt->bind_result($student_id, $student_first_name, $student_last_name, $agency_id, $user_email, $agency_name, $agency_rep_name, $agency_phone, $personal_id, $english_name, $gender, $date_of_birth, $fathers_name, $fathers_email, $fathers_date_of_birth, $fathers_phone_number, $fathers_occupation, $mothers_name, $mothers_email, $mothers_date_of_birth, $mothers_phone_number, $mothers_occupation, $address_1, $address_2, $city, $province, $country, $postal_code, $home_phone, $mobile_phone, $in_grade, $starting_grade, $medical_insurance, $homestay_placement, $emergency_id, $emerg_first_name, $emerg_last_name, $emerg_email, $emerg_relationship, $emerg_home_phone, $emerg_mobile_phone, $emerg_address_1, $emerg_address_2, $emerg_postal_code, $emerg_city, $emerg_province, $emerg_country, $academic_id, $school_choice_1, $school_choice_2, $school_choice_3, $preferred_community, $study_duration, $needs_canadian_credits, $arrival_date, $final_school_date, $departure_date, $years_of_english, $speaking_english, $writing_english, $subject_area_1, $subject_area_2, $subject_area_3, $subject_area_4, $subject_area_5, $subject_area_6, $required_courses, $graduation_goals, $education_goals, $semester_start, $legalization, $aboutme_id, $nationality, $religion, $language_at_home, $siblings, $how_many_siblings, $lived_in_english_country, $which_english_country, $how_long_in_english_country, $personality, $family_preference, $dietary_requirements, $my_dietary_requirements, $food_preference, $fav_foods, $least_fav_foods, $reading_genre, $social_media, $additional_info, $hobbies, $play_instrument, $which_instrument, $like_sports, $which_sports, $belong_to_clubs, $which_clubs, $religious_service, $prefer_religious_service, $household_chores, $have_curfew, $weekday_curfew, $weekend_curfew, $expectations, $been_away_from_family, $concerns_about_canada, $allergies_medical_disabilities, $airport_pickup, $file_id, $file_name, $file_type, $file_size, $file_path);
        if($stmt->num_rows !==1){
            $error_msg['finalize_button'] = 'There was no student found with a completed application.';
        }//End If no Rows are found
            else{
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$student_first_nam.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$agency_name.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$english_name.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$emerg_first_name.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$school_choice_1.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$religion.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$file_id.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$file_name.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$file_type.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$file_size.'</span></li>';
                $body .= '<li><span>'.$file_path.'</span></li>';
            }
    }
}
```

I feel like I am on the right track but It just aint working. Sorry for the novel but wanted to explain as best as I could

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your query.

```
WHERE p.student_id AND e.student_id AND a.student_id AND m.student_id AND f.student_id = ?
```

does not do what you want it to do. What you mean is

```
WHERE p.student_id = ? AND e.student_id = ? AND a.student_id = ? AND m.student_id = ? AND f.student_id = ?
```

However, you don't need to put all those fields in your `WHERE` clause at all, since you joined those tables using that very same criterion.

All students, agencies etc. will be repeated as many times as there are associated file records, so you need to keep that in mind when displaying the data.

Comment: Actually if I use your example, I receive the same empty array even with one or no files added.

Comment: @bilcker If no files is a possibility you should use an outer join. Could you post your updated query (and not all on one line please)?

Comment: Ok I have edited my original question with my query in its entirety. I have entered this exact query into phpmyadmin and it worked fine retrieving everything I need but on the web it returns [  ] when I look ate the returned response.

Comment: @bilcker I can't immediately see what's wrong with your code, except for the things I already mentioned. In your where clause you are just evaluating student ID as booleans so you should get rid of those lines. You should allow for results with more than 1 row since there can be multiple uploaded files. You should `LEFT JOIN` the uploaded_files table. Thanks for formatting your query over multiple lines. Just to make sure: you didn't do that in your actual code right? Does `mysqli_error` tell you anything?